# Is there any analog of GetUpdateRect() for .NET without importing Win32 API?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not opposed, just seems like using native .NET stuff would be better.  I am looking to get the update rect for code within a custom control.  I am using c# in Visual Studio '17 if that matters. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the property you would use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.cliprectangle?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: Great!  I'm gonna check that out.   I'm wishing now that the .NET docs would list in the "See Also" section any Win32 API calls that relate to a current search result... to help go from that to .NET. -Thanks  PS - I'll making some posts with related questions soon.